# How to operate SAFE_ORDINAL in big query

Tags: google-bigquery

UPDATED....TRYING AGAIN:

I'm working with this query:

```
Select FirstName, LastName, MiddleName, Gender, Age, DOB, Address, Address2, City, State, Zip, Zip4, TimeZone, Income, HomeValue, Networth, MaritalStatus, IsRenter, HasChildren, CreditRating, Investor, LinesOfCredit, InvestorRealEstate, Traveler, Pets, MailResponder, Charitable, PolicalDonations, PoliticalParty, Attom_ID, GEOID, Score, Score1, Score2, Score3, Score4, Score5, Latitude, Longitude, Email[SAFE_ORDINAL(1)] Email1, Email[SAFE_ORDINAL(2)] Email2, Email[SAFE_ORDINAL(3)] Email3
from (

Select
  P.FirstName, P.LastName, MiddleName, Gender, Age, DOB, P.Address, Address2, P.City, P.State, P.Zip, Zip4, TimeZone, Income, HomeValue, Networth, MaritalStatus, IsRenter, HasChildren, CreditRating, Investor, LinesOfCredit, InvestorRealEstate, Traveler, Pets, MailResponder, Charitable, PolicalDonations, PoliticalParty, Attom_ID, GEOID, Score, Score1, Score2, Score3, Score4, Score5, Latitude, Longitude, E.Email
from `mother-216719.People.PEOPLE` P
join `mother-216719.People.EMAIL_STAGE` E on 
  P.FirstName = E.FirstName
  and P.LastName = E.LastName
  and P.Address = E.Address
  and P.Zip = E.Zip
 ) a
```

It is a straight JOIN between PEOPLE and EMAIL_STAGE.
ALL FIELDS that are `P.*` and without alias come from PEOPLE, while EMAIL comes from EMAIL_STAGE as a string.

The EMAIL_STAGE table has First Name, Last Name, Address, City, State, Zip, and EMAIL.  Those seven fields alone.  The PEOPLE table have the other fields, and several others not needed.

I'm joining on email to attach emails to PEOPLE via address matching.  The key here is that the relationship is one-to-many and there could be many emails to PEOPLE.I want to add EMAIL1, EMAIL2, EMAIL3 into PEOPLE.  I want the emails to come from EMAIL_STAGE's one-to-many relationship from PEOPLE.

My first recommendation was to perform a PIVOT like maneuver using NTH(), but then was told SAFE_ORDINAL[] was the SQL Standard-version term I wanted. The above query was the result and the structure error in the query is the problem I'm trying to achieve.

From the join, how do I PIVOT the first three found emails (order not-withstanding), and place them into EMAIL1, EMAIL2, EMAIL3?

Thank you.

**UPDATED #2.**

Example dataset from the STAGE_EMAIL table:

#### FirstName|LastName|Address|City|State|Zip|Email

Jael|Baird|616 Lobortis Ave|Melipilla|Metropolitana de Santiago|4513|vulputate.ullamcorper.magna@Crasvulputate.edu
Yvette|Ellison|P.O. Box 847, 5270 Ut Rd.|Gasteiz|Euskadi|549851|Quisque.porttitor.eros@Duissit.org
Lacota|Head|P.O. Box 161, 7347 Elit St.|Coutisse|NA|E5R 7B5|metus.vitae@egestasa.com
Victor|Hensley|398-3949 Eget, St.|Lagos|Lagos|LI8 2ND|rhoncus.Proin@Phasellus.org

Comment: "by grabbing the first three emails" What is the format of the `Email` column? It's a `STRING`, not an `ARRAY`, so you can't use the bracket operator on it...

Comment: Please edit your question to show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can try to help. You can also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ok.  tried again.

Comment: provide an example of `EMAIL` field

Comment: The email field is a standard string.  but has protected info.  meaning personal addresses and email addresses.  I can't give you an example.  the best is to fake something.  want that?

Comment: what are the keys in EMAIL_STAGE table? As of example for email - i wanted to make sure that the string represents one email and not the list of emails. so `abc@xyz.com` or `abc1@xyz.com, abc2@xyz.com,  abc3@xyz.com` was perfectly ok what that :o)

Comment: Address, City, State, Zip.  In the query, the JOIN is showing the proper key management here.  The tables were built that way for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT FirstName, LastName, MiddleName, Gender, Age, DOB, Address, Address2, City, State, Zip, Zip4, TimeZone, Income, HomeValue, Networth, MaritalStatus, IsRenter, HasChildren, CreditRating, Investor, LinesOfCredit, InvestorRealEstate, Traveler, Pets, MailResponder, Charitable, PolicalDonations, PoliticalParty, Attom_ID, GEOID, Score, Score1, Score2, Score3, Score4, Score5, Latitude, Longitude, 
  Emails[SAFE_ORDINAL(1)] Email1, Emails[SAFE_ORDINAL(2)] Email2, Emails[SAFE_ORDINAL(3)] Email3
FROM (
  SELECT
    P.FirstName, P.LastName, MiddleName, Gender, Age, DOB, P.Address, Address2, P.City, P.State, P.Zip, Zip4, TimeZone, Income, HomeValue, Networth, MaritalStatus, IsRenter, HasChildren, CreditRating, Investor, LinesOfCredit, InvestorRealEstate, Traveler, Pets, MailResponder, Charitable, PolicalDonations, PoliticalParty, Attom_ID, GEOID, Score, Score1, Score2, Score3, Score4, Score5, Latitude, Longitude, E.Email
  FROM `mother-216719.People.PEOPLE` P
  JOIN (
    SELECT FirstName, LastName, Address, Zip, ARRAY_AGG(Email) Emails
    FROM `mother-216719.People.EMAIL_STAGE`
    GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, Address, Zip
  ) E 
  ON P.FirstName = E.FirstName
  AND P.LastName = E.LastName
  AND P.Address = E.Address
  AND P.Zip = E.Zip
) a
```

Note: not tested, so let know if still issue;
Also, subselect for E potentially can be adjusted to whatever fields you need to pick from EMAIL_STAGE - I am leaving this to you to complete as needed

Comment: This query is awesome, however, It is causing an excessive resources error.  I am thinking it's the subquery "E" in the middle.  got anyway I can put some efficiency to it?

Comment: I answered your specific question regarding emails w/o changing actually your query, so that error is subject for different question. Meantime - are you sure you are running exact that query? Or you have something else there, like ORDER BY FOR EXAMPLE - this would explain the resource error